# Javascript, execute function only for a certain div ID

Tags: javascript, function

I want to know how I can use javascript (not jquery) to execute a function only for a certain DIV that has a ID. For example to find a certain text inside this div with ID="content".

Thanks.

Comment: Very googleable question. Hence the minus 1.

Comment: believe me I searched, that's why I'm here.. you are so fast with the hatting

Comment: @AdrianM. I'm guessing you searched for the exact answer to your question. Sometimes, in this workaday world we live in, you have to do just a little thinking to come up with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("content")
someFunction(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
someFunction(elem) {
    if (elem.id != "content" || elem.tagName != "DIV")
        throw new Error("wrong element");
    return find(elem, text);
}
someFunction(document.getElementById("content")); // works
someFunction(document.body.firstChild); // throws error
```

Comment: defensive programming like this is a waste of time

Comment: Surely it is, but that's what the op wanted, isn't it?

Comment: I would favour "assume the OP can't speak english and interpret his question in the least WTF manner"